# Show Projects Assigned to a User Who Logins From Projects Assigned To Many Users

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two tables tbl_Staff which contains the User details and tbl_ProjectInformation which contains the project details which are assigned to different users.

What I need to do is , When a user logins I want to show only the list of projects of tbl_ProjectInformation which are assigned to the user who logins in form FrmUserRole on datagridview
dgvGetUserProject.

**LoginForm Code:**

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable result = uc.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();

            string role = result.Rows[0]["Roles"].ToString();


            switch (role)
            {
                case "Admin":
                    UserPanelFrm frm = new UserPanelFrm();
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    break;
                case "User":
                    FrmUserRole fur = new FrmUserRole();
                    fur.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD");
            txtPassword.Clear();
            txtPassword.Focus();
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

**tbl_Staff**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Staff](
    [StaffID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [JoinedDate] [date] NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [date] NULL,
    [Roles] [nvarchar](200)
)
```

**tbl_ProjectInformation**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_ProjectInformation](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BusinessName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ContactPerson] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [date] NULL,
    [AssignedTo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CompletedDate] [date] Null
)
```

What I have done is bind the datagrid view to a table but coundn't understand to pass the login user id to sql script. Following are the script I used to get project list of only one user. I need to pass login user StaffId to sql script and show project assigned to that StaffId User.

**ProjcetClass.css**

```
public DataTable SelectUserProjects()
    { 
        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select tbl_ProjectInformation.ProjectID,tbl_ProjectInformation.BusinessName,tbl_ProjectInformation.ContactPerson,tbl_ProjectInformation.Phone,tbl_ProjectInformation.Address,tbl_ProjectInformation.CreatedDate,tbl_ProjectInformation.Status,tbl_ProjectInformation.CompletedDate from tbl_ProjectInformation,tbl_Staff where tbl_Staff.StaffID='7'", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**DataGrid View Binding in FrmUserRole**

```
    private void FrmUserRole_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvGetUserProject.DataSource = pc.SelectUserProjects();

    }
```

Comment: You need to have a control (say, a DataGridView) on a window and bind the result table (or its defaultview) to it.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem, thank you for your suggestion. I have added the codes for binding could you please suggest what to do next.